# How to change animation speed using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code

```
.test2{
transition: 10s;  
}
```

js

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  $( ".test2" ).animate({
  top: -s-100 }, 0, "linear");  
  }
```

or

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  $('.test2').css('transition',  0);  
  $('.test2').css('transition',  "");  
  }
```

But nothing happened. It should be when I scroll down the page with the wheel or click the mouse on the scroll bar at this moment transition: 0s; but the moment I stop doing it. then the transition immediately becomes 10s
When you click on the button, the animation should be smooth.

Is it possible to do something like this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/aMBvKO) example

Comment: Afaik, transition needs to know *what* to transition.  All you've given it is the duration, not the property to transition when it changes.  Also, jQuery `animate()` does not use the css transition property at all.  `animate()` is written to allow browsers who do not have inherient animation ability to still have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

just a little code, havent tested it, but i hope its close to what you are looking for, using `offset()` to retrieve the top position whenever you scroll the page..

and set the `xtop` variable, and then to call the `doAnimation()` each time the page scrolls, but remember to call the `stop()` method on each object, so the animation cache doesn't cue up and slow down your system.

```
var xtop;

window.onScroll = function(){
    xtop = $(window).offset().top; //get the top position.
    doAnimation();
}

function doAnimation(){
   $(".test2").stop().animate({top: xtop}, 10000, "linear");  
}
```

whenever you stop scrolling, the object animates to the `xtop` position in 10s (10000 milliseconds), i hope it works.

Comment: did not help I edited the code but I don't know how to remove $(".test2").animate({transition: "0s"}, 1 );  }  So I had to make a crutch
You do not know how to fix it? https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/aMBvKO